# Do Javascript Objects Have a Parent/Child Relationship?

Tags: javascript

Take this code, as an example, forget what's actually going on in the code and just imagine this is any js code, I only picked this because it's a little bit "long":

```
document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d").fillStyle="#FF0000";
```

Are the objects to the left "parents" of the objects to the right? Or are they all "unrelated" and just sort of "foster" one another for lack of a better word?

And I don't mean this in the programming sense of the word "parent" and "child" (like with xml or html) I mean it as analogous to an actual "child" and an actual "parent" in that the parent is unique to the child and the child is unique to the parent.  That's why I added in the "foster" part (where they are not necessarily related by blood...nor are they permanently attached to the object on the left).

In other words, are the objects to the right exclusively subsets of the objects to the left?  Or are they sometimes shared, sometimes not shared by other objects to the left?

Answer (score 3):

In *general*, no, there's no exclusivity. Consider:

```
var a = {};
var b = {};
var c = {};
a.foo = c;
b.bar = c;
```

Both `a` and `b` now have properties referring to `c`. For that matter:

```
c.a = a;
c.b = b;
```

Now `c` has properties referring back to `a` and `b`. And `a` could have a property referring to `b` if you wanted. (Or `b` to `a`. Or both.)

In the specific example you gave, it's unlikely that the canvas's 2D context is used by any other canvas. But that's a canvas thing, not a JavaScript thing. And similarly, in client-side JavaScript we're frequently dealing with DOM elements, and the DOM has parent/child relationships. But that's a DOM thing, not a JavaScript thing.

Answer (score 0):

What you have described are DOM objects. The DOM has a structure that is hierarchical.

So, for instance, if you call the method `object.getElementsByTagName`, it will only return children of `object`. So in your example, the objects on the right are subsets of those on the left, yes.

But there is no reason for javascript objects in general to have any sort of hierarchy.

Ie `obj1.getSomething().getSomethingElse().returnProperty()` does not have to return a property that has any relationship whatsoever to `obj1`.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty cool, so these objects are just all sort of sharable by one another?  Or is there some underlying logic determining which objects "go" with each other?

Comment: There is no underlying logic built into the language itself.